# Creating weblogic domain on unix/linux?

Tags: java, unix, weblogic

I  need to create new weblogic domain on ubumtu server which does not have GUI ? I did google but did not
find any steps where i could install with GUI on linux/ubutntu server.

Is there any command for linux  with which i can create domain ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be straightforward. Please, find below few links where you can find all the steps:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20593_01/doc.560/e23613/config_weblogic.htm
https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/entry/steps_to_create_a_domain

I hope this can help you

Comment: it says `The Fusion Middleware Configuration Wizard Welcome screen is displayed.` but i don't have GUI installed on it

Comment: You should run the ./serverXX_linux32.bin and by default, the console mode will be started. For example: Extracting 0%….100%
Unable to instantiate GUI, defaulting to console mode.
<- Oracle Installer – WebLogic Platform XXX  ->
Welcome:
—
This installer will guide you through the installation of WebLogic Platform XXX Type “Next” or enter to proceed to the next prompt. If you want to
change data entered previously, type “Previous”. You may quit the installer at any time by typing “Exit”
Enter [Exit][Next]> Next
<- Oracle Installer – WebLogic Platform XXX ->
Choose BEA Home Directory:

Comment: sorry i did not get you. When i run `run config.sh` it does not do anything ??

Comment: But where is  serverXX_linux32.bin?

Comment: You also can set the console model as ./config.sh -mode=console

Comment: I set the mode to console and nothing happens. I also looked at the help screen and the only two modes available are gui and silent. Nothing happens when I try to run the config.sh script. If I specify ./config -mode=silent nothing happens if I specify ./config -mode=gui.

Answer (score 0):

You have two other option besides GUI which are console mode installation and silent mode installation.I recommend console mode, it is easier than silent mode.

1) console mode installation
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/install/console.html

2)silent mode installation

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/install/silent.html

Answer (score 0):

Till 11g domain creation you can use console mode. If you run config.sh by default you will get console mode if GUI is not available.

For 12c console mode is not available hence you must use wlst to create domains.

Have you tried using xming by enabling X11 forwarding? This might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/x11-forwarding